# Loop pandas directory

Tags: python, pandas

I have many csv files in a directory with two column each

```
miRNA  read_counts  
miR1      10
miR1      5
miR2      2
miR2      3
miR3     100
```

I would like to sum read_counts if the miRNA id is the same.

Result:

```
miRNA  read_counts  
miR1      15
miR2      5
miR3     100
```

To do that I wrote a little script. However I don't know how to loop it through all my csv files so I don't have to copy paste file names and output each time. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks for the help!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("modified_LC1a_miRNA_expressed.csv")
df_new = df.groupby('miRNA')['read_count'].sum()
print(df_new)
df_new.to_csv('sum_LC1a_miRNA_expressed.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into `glob` module.

```
from glob import glob
import os

path = "./your/path"
files = glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

dataframes = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # rest you would want to append these to dataframes
    dataframes.append(df)
```

Then, use `pd.concat` to join the dataframes and perform the `groupby` operation.

**EDIT 1:**
Based on the request mentioned in the comment:

```
results = {}
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # perform operation
    df_new = df.groupby('miRNA')['read_count'].sum()
    results[file] = df_new
```

Comment: Thanks, However, I don't really want to get one unique file. I want to perform the same operation in each file and give me an individual  output for each of them.

Comment: Well, in that case you would want to perform the operation inside the loop and append the results or keep them in a dictionary! Nevertheless, the question asked above problem was related to reading multiple files and not about performing the operation.

Comment: Added to the changes requested, I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Somehow not working, I'm going through it. I have no output. I'll keep trying. Thanks a lot !

Comment: `results = {}
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # perform operation
    df_new = df.groupby('miRNA')['read_count'].sum()
    results[file] = df_new
    df_new.to.csv()`

Comment: Can you please provide the directories and the filenames?

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to steal the answer. I would have put this in a comment under @Asif Ali's answer if I had enough rep.

Assuming all input .csv files follow the format:
"modified_{rest_of_the_file_name}.csv"

And you want the outputs to be:
"sum_{same_rest_of_the_file_name}.csv"

```
import os
import glob

path = "./your/path"
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_new = df.groupby('miRNA')['read_count'].sum()
    print(df_new)
    df_new.to_csv(file.split('modified')[:-1] + \
                  'sum' + \
                  '_'.join(file.split('modified')[-1:]))
```

Comment: I am trying to do it but not giving me any output neither. I'll keep trying to see if I have some mistake and update here. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I adjusted the last line to be more universal to the file path. Try it now.

Comment: Still not working, no output. Your code does seems good and understandable, so I don't know whats the problem with my machine.
Even when I tried just to print the output I got nothing.

Comment: This is what I got line by line:
`import pandas as pd
import os
from glob import glob


path = "./Users/user/Desktop/2019.11.28_for_DESEQ2"
files = glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_new = df.groupby('miRNA')['read_count'].sum()
    print(df_new)
    df_new.to_csv(file.split('modified')[0] + \
                  'sum' + \
                  '_'.join(file.split('modified')[1:]))`

Comment: Try it with removing the dot from the beginning of your filepath

Comment: Yes, just found out that works for some of my files. I am gonna check my files now. Thanks